# HTML and CSS img is connected how to separate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the code:

```css
body{
        background-image:url('http://wallpoper.com/images/00/31/33/51/black-background_00313351.jpg');
    }

    div.header{
        background-color:#F0F8FF;
        text-align:center;
        padding:3px;
        opacity:0.2;
        height:60px;
    }
    h1{
        font-family:'Lucida Console';
        font-weight:bold;
        color:blue;
    }
    div.header ul {
        font-style:none;
        font-size:50%;
        list-style-type:none;
        position:relative;
        right:700px;
        bottom:50px;
    }
     ul{

        list-style-type:none;
        line-height:220%;
    }
    a:link{
        color:white;
        font-size:150%;
        text-decoration:none;

    }
    a:visited{
        color:white;
        font-size:150%;
        text-decoration:none;
        margin:10px;
    }
    a:hover{
        font-size:220%;
        color:    #7CB9E8;
    }
    div.gallary img{
    position:relative;
    left:160px;
    top:150px;
    margin:5px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;

    }

    img:hover{
        width:220px;
        height:220px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "header">
            <h1>Gordong Guitar Lesson</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Mailbox:147ox</li>
                <li>phone: (151)-232-4576</li>
                <li>Zip:223</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class +"nav" >
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href = "">Lessons</a></li>
                <li><a href = "">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a href = "">apply</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "gallary">
            <img src = "http://www.londonguitaracademy.com/wp-content/uploads/guitar-lessons1.jpg"></img>
            <img src = "http://lessonsthatrock.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/guitar-lessons-long-beach1.jpg"></img>
            <img src = "http://tampabaymusicacademy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/guitarlessons.jpg"></img>
            <img src = "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUpvERhA8lpbGi7ic9GGThcF20NZl1ZrDTT_N-mqvZwTqdpw7vMA"></img>
            <img src = "http://hobartguitarlessons.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/guitar-man-new_221.jpg?w=300&h=300"></img>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My questions is when I run this code and hover over the links or the images,
They all seem to be connected through some invisible box. For example when I hover over the "Home" link. Every link and every `img` moves downward. How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: you need to provide your css also

Comment: i think its free flowin on the bottom

Comment: Shouldn't this be = and not + 
<div class +"nav" >

Comment: @Syndrome z please check my answer. It's working perfect on the fiddle as well

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
a:link{
    color:white;
    font-size:150%;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
    font-size:220%;
    color:  #7CB9E8;
}
```

This means when you move the mouse over a link (`<a>`), your font size becomes 220% instead of the regular 150% - that's what is causing the moving you describe - the size of any text will increase by approximately 50% (150/220).

EDIT / ADDED:

And the same with images (`<img>`tags) - you have:

```
div.gallary img{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
img:hover{
  width:220px;
  height:220px;
}
```

which means: Your images in `<div class="gallary">`are 200x200px, but when you move the mouse over them, they become bigger: 220x220px, which also moves everything that comes after it...

Answer (score 0):

They are not connected at all, they are just responding to the elements growth because your links are making your font bigger on hover and your images are getting border on hover.

The best way to avoid this behavior is setting the `border-sizing` property:

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

[* { Box-sizing: Border-box } FTW](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) by Paul Irish

Comment: I counter-argument to that: what if I *want* to be able to fit a 600px object (say, an image) inside my element that will have padding and a border? Well now I have to define `width:608px` or whatever. The problem has been reversed.

Comment: Is not a counter argument at all, using box-sizing is considered a good practice and if you want to do stuff the old way is up to you, just remove the lines.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/j9rxzc2n/

please check this one it's misbehaving because its size was being increased while hovering. so I fixed its size, now it's working fine without up and down.
I only added this one line: `ul li{height:30px; }`

Comment: Images still have ops problem

Comment: Now I'm sure this is fixed. If not let me know

Comment: Did you check my comment link? There you'll be able to only see the border but not the resizing of the images. earlier it's bordering on hover, but in normal. Now I set the border everytime and changed the color of border on hover. Please check it again, it's not being resized.

Comment: if it's not like that you want, can you give me an sketched image as you need?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/8ktphwyo/

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://wallpoper.com/images/00/31/33/51/black-background_00313351.jpg');
}

div.header {
  background-color: #F0F8FF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  height: 60px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lucida Console';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

div.header ul {
  font-style: none;
  font-size: 50%;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 700px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 220%;
}

a:link {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform-origin: left;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  color: #7CB9E8;
}

div.gallary img {
  position: relative;
  left: 160px;
  top: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

div.gallary img:hover {
  z-index: 100;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Gordong Guitar Lesson</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Mailbox:147ox</li>
    <li>phone: (151)-232-4576</li>
    <li>Zip:223</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lessons</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Apply</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="gallary">
  <img src="http://www.londonguitaracademy.com/wp-content/uploads/guitar-lessons1.jpg" />
  <img src="http://lessonsthatrock.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/guitar-lessons-long-beach1.jpg" />
  <img src="http://tampabaymusicacademy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/guitarlessons.jpg" />
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUpvERhA8lpbGi7ic9GGThcF20NZl1ZrDTT_N-mqvZwTqdpw7vMA" />
  <img src="http://hobartguitarlessons.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/guitar-man-new_221.jpg?w=300&h=300" />
</div>
```

I've made it so none of the size changes effect the page flow. I've used css scaling rather than actually changing the size values and for borders I gave each image an invisible border that was coloured in rather than adding a border after.